# How to avoid that Entity Framework must be installed for each project which uses the DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, data-access-layer

I have a solution which contains several UI projects and a bunch of common (shared) DLL projects. There also is a "DB access project" based on EF which contains the models and DbContext and is referenced by the UI projects.

The problem now is, that for each UI project that uses the DbContext from the "DB access project" I have to install the Entity Framework NuGet package. The problem gets worse when I have to update EF. Then I always have to take care that all projects using EF have installed the same EF version.

Is there a better solution? The correct way for me seems to only have to install EF in one place, the "DB access project".

I also thought about something like hiding EF and the DbSets behind proxy objects only to avoid references to EF.

When I omit the EF reference I get errors like

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'DbContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

and

```
Error   CS0012  The type 'DbSet<>' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to expose the DbContext from the DAL Layer ? The DAL layer should ideally expose a class which uses the Dbcontext or Dbset. There shoudn't be any EF depdendencies on your UI Layer. There are multiple ways to achieve this. One commonly used pattern is called Repository Pattern.

You can see the E,g here

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I think it is not DAL in a classical way. In my "DB access project" I bunch together all objects that affect database access. Mainly this is the DbContext (which exposes some DbSets) and the model classes. In the UI projects, I work with the DbContext and the DbSets directly.

Comment: If you need to use DbSet and Dbcontext in your UI projects then you need reference to the EF. You can't avoid using it.

Comment: to manage the EF versions for all the projects you need not install it to all the projects individually. Inside VS you can right click on the solution and choose the Manage Nuget Packages Solutions for Solution. There you can invidually choose the projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is typically an example that shows why it isn't wise to expose the insides of your database to the outer world.

You should expose the sequences of data on which your uses want to be able to perform Linq statements. Usually it is enough to expose the classes of your DbSets of your DbContext as IQueryable collections. This is quite often called the Repository pattern.

If you hadn't a repository, then users would create an object of your DbContext class. Then they would use the DbSets of the DbContext to access your tables as IQueryable. Use these IQueryables to create and execute the queries, possibley use SaveChanges. Finally they would Dispose the DbContext,.

The repository is used similarly. Users of your Repository would create a Repository object. Access IQueryables that represent your tables. Perform the linq, possibley SaveChanges and Dispose the Repository.

If you only want to allow queries, expose IQueryable objects, if you want to be able To Add / Update / Remove fetched items, also add Add / Remove / SaveChanges functions.

If you expose these functions as interfaces, you can unit test your code by simply replacing your DbContext by an in-memory unit-test database, or sometimes just by using Lists.

For example a School context with Students, Teachers, Grades: Teachers have many Students; Students have many Teachers (many-to-many); Students have zero or more Grades, every Grade belongs to exactly one student (one-to-many).

All items in the School context are identified by an Id: they all implement IId. This is used to enable a generic class to fetch your items by Id

### Queries only

Your DbContext with the interfaces:

```
interface IId
{
     public int Id {get;}
}

class Teacher : IId {...}
class Student: IId {...}
class Grade: IId {...}

interface ISchoolQuerier
{
    IQueryable<Teacher> Teachers {get; }
    IQueryable<Student> Students {get;}
    IQueryable<Grade> Grades {get;}
}

class SchoolDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Teacher> Teachers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Grades> {get; set;}

    // explicit interface implementation
    IQueryable<Teacher> ISchoolQuerier.Teachers {get{return this.Teachers;}}
    IQueryable<Student> ISchoolQuerier.Students {get{return this.Students;}}
    IQueryable<Grade> ISchoolQuerier.Grades{get{return this.Grades;}}
}
```

The SchoolRepository that uses this SchoolDbContext

```
class SchoolRepository : IDisposable, ISchoolQuerier
{
    private SchoolRepository() : this (ISchoolQuerier)(new SchoolDbContext())
    {   // default constructor used default SchoolDbContext
    }

    private SchoolRepository(ISchoolQuerier querier)
    {   // use the provided querier
        // this constructor is useful for unit tests
        this.querier = querier;
    }

    private bool isDisposed = false;
    private readonly ISchoolQuerier;

    #region IDisposable
    public void Dispose()
    {
         this.Dispose(true);
         GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    public void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
         if (disposing && !this.isDisposed)
         {
             IDisposable disposableSchool = this.SchoolQuerier as IDisposable;
             if (disposableSchool != null)
             {
                 this.schoolDbContext.Dispose();
             }
             this.isDisposed = true;
         }
    }
    #endregion IDispose

    #region ISchoolQuerier
    public IQueryable<Teacher> Teachers {get{return this.SchoolDbContext.Teachers;}}
    public IQueryable<Student> Students {get{return this.SchoolDbContext.Students;}}
```

public IQueryable Grades {get{return this.SchoolDbContext.Grades;}} 
        #endregion ISchoolQuerier
    }

Users would use it similar to how they would use the SchoolContext:

```
using (var schoolRepository = new SchoolRepository())
{
     var youngStudents = schoolRepository.Students
         .Where(student => student.Birthday > ...)
         .Select(student => new {...});
}
```

The SchoolRepository has two constructors. The default constructor uses the default DbContext. The other constructor uses the provided ISchoolQuerier. This other constructor can be useful for unit tests, where you can provide a class with three collections to test simple queries

If you only expose the interface ISchoolQuerier to users, then they don't have to install entity framework. You are also free to change internally how you access your database. Don't fancy entity framework anymore? Go ahead, use Dapper from now on, users won't notice the difference!

### Change the database

If you want to add / update / delete items it consider creating a separate interface for it. Only those who have that interface can update / delete items.

Here I used the earlier defined IId

```
interface IChangeableSet<T> : IQueryable<T> : where T: IId
{
    public T Get(int id)
    public T Add(T item);
    public T Remove(int Id);
    public T Remove(T item);
}

class DbSet<T> : IChangeableSet<T> : where T: IId
{
    public DbSet(System.Data.Entity.IDbset<T> dbSet)
    {
        this.dbset = dbSet
    }

    private readonly System.Data.Entity.IDbSet<T> dbSet;

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return this.DbSet.Where(item => item.Id == id).SingleOrDefault();
        // here is where I uses that all items implement IId
    }
    public T Add(T item)
    {
         return this.dbSet.Add(item);
    }
    ... // TODO: fill the other functions
}
```

The SchoolRepository implements this interface (preferrably explicit implementatin)

```
class ChangeableSchoolRepository : IDisposable, ISchoolQuerier
{
    public ChangeableSchoolRepository(SchooldDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.schoolDbContext = dbContext;
    }
    private readonly SchoolDbContext;

    public IChangeableSet<Teacher> Teachers
    {
        get {return new DbSet(dbContext.Teachers);}
    }
    ... // etc for Students / Grades

    public void SaveChanges()
    {
        return this.SchoolDbcontext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your approach: you present two repositories. The first one `SchoolRepository` doesn't have the `DbContext` in the constructor signature (and thus it possibly doesn't make the client reference the EF) but it's flawed - it creates an instance of the `DbContext` by itself, thus making it impossible to have an explicit lifetime management for the injected context (this antipattern is called the **Bastard Injection**). The other repository, the `ChangeableSchoolRepository` as an explicit context in the constructor, thus, it forces the client to reference the EF.

Comment: Of course, the latter is correct - the top level code, the **Compositon Root** composes all dependencies, including explicit setting DbContext instances for repositories. I am not sure the OP is aware this is unavoidable at least in a top level project.

Comment: If I make sure that all my IDispoable objects are really Disposed when not used anymore, preferrably using a using statement, then I thought it is exactly defined when the objects are Disposed. If you use the default constructor the DbContext is disposed when the repository is disposed. If you use the other constructor, who am I to Dispose it: my creator may want to use it after I am disposed. Of course, because he created the DbContext it is his job to Dispose it properly, is it not?

Comment: There are numerous scenarios where you want a **shared** instance of the dbcontext injected into the repository, e.g. when you have multiple repositories in a single Unit of Work and they all share the per-http-request DbContext, possibly reuse the EF's 1st level cache etc. That's why your latter approach is more correct. However, it doesn't necessarily solve OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

I now use the following solution. In general, I encapsulated the functionality of EF and IQueryable that I require in three proxy objects.

Instead of using the EF DbContext directly, I now use a proxy object (the DataStore class) that offers me the DbSets (repositories).

The EF DbSets exposed by the DbContext I wrapped into a generic Repository, which exposes the functionality required to work with the data. The Repository itself is derived from DbQueryProxy which proxies the EF DbQuery.

Now I can comfortably work with the data in a familiar way:

```
using (var db = new DataStore())
{
    var students = db.Students.DoSomeLinq(...);
    var teachers = db.Teachers.SomeLinq(...);

    // do some work ...
    // note: The entities in students and teachers are still bound to the DbContext internal to DataStore!

    // optional 
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

**DataStore:**

```
public class DataStore : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;

    #region constructors

    public DataStore()
    {
        _dbContext = new DbContext();
    }

    #endregion constructors

    internal DbContext Context => _dbContext;

    public void RemoveRange<TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) where TEntity : EntityBase => _dbContext.RemoveRange(entities);

    #region db sets

    public Repository<Teacher> Teachers => _dbContext.Teachers; // implicit type conversion from DbSet<TEntity> to Repository<TEntity>!
    public Repository<Student> Students => _dbContext.Students;
    public Repository<Grade> Grades => _dbContext.Grade;

    #endregion db sets

    #region DbContext

    public void Dispose() => _dbContext.Dispose();

    public int SaveChanges() => _dbContext.SaveChanges();

    public Repository<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : EntityBase => _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => _dbContext.Equals(obj);

    public override int GetHashCode() => _dbContext.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => _dbContext.ToString();

    #endregion DbContext
}
```

**Repository<TEntity>:**

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : DbQueryProxy<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<TEntity> _DbSet;

    internal Repository(DbSet<TEntity> dbSet) : base(dbSet)
    {
        _DbSet = dbSet;
    }

    private Repository()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator DbSet<TEntity>(Repository<TEntity> entry) => entry._DbSet;

    public static implicit operator Repository<TEntity>(DbSet<TEntity> entry) => new Repository<TEntity>(entry);

    #region DbSet<TEntity>

    public TEntity Add(TEntity entity) => _DbSet.Add(entity);

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> AddRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) => _DbSet.AddRange(entities);

    public TEntity Attach(TEntity entity) => _DbSet.Attach(entity);

    public TDerivedEntity Create<TDerivedEntity>() where TDerivedEntity : class, TEntity => _DbSet.Create<TDerivedEntity>();

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => _DbSet.Equals(obj);

    public override int GetHashCode() => _DbSet.GetHashCode();

    public TEntity Find(params object[] keyValues) => _DbSet.Find(keyValues);

    public Task<TEntity> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues) => _DbSet.FindAsync(keyValues);

    public Task<TEntity> FindAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, params object[] keyValues) => _DbSet.FindAsync(cancellationToken, keyValues);

    public TEntity Remove(TEntity entity) => _DbSet.Remove(entity);

    public IEnumerable<TEntity> RemoveRange(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities) => _DbSet.RemoveRange(entities);

    #endregion DbSet<TEntity>
}
```

**DbQueryProxy<TEntity>:**

```
public class DbQueryProxy<TResult> : IOrderedQueryable<TResult>, IListSource
{
    private readonly DbQuery<TResult> _DbQuery;

    internal DbQueryProxy(DbQuery<TResult> entry)
    {
        _DbQuery = entry;
    }

    protected DbQueryProxy()
    {
    }

    public static implicit operator DbQuery<TResult>(DbQueryProxy<TResult> entry) => entry._DbQuery;

    public static implicit operator DbQueryProxy<TResult>(DbQuery<TResult> entry) => new DbQueryProxy<TResult>(entry);

    #region Interfaces

    Type IQueryable.ElementType => ((IQueryable)_DbQuery).ElementType;

    Expression IQueryable.Expression => ((IQueryable)_DbQuery).Expression;

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => ((IQueryable)_DbQuery).Provider;

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable)_DbQuery).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator<TResult> IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<TResult>)_DbQuery).GetEnumerator();

    bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection => ((IListSource)_DbQuery).ContainsListCollection;

    IList IListSource.GetList() => ((IListSource)_DbQuery).GetList();

    #endregion Interfaces

    #region DbQuery<TResult>

    public string Sql => _DbQuery.Sql;

    public DbQueryProxy<TResult> AsNoTracking() => _DbQuery.AsNoTracking();

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => _DbQuery.Equals(obj);

    public override int GetHashCode() => _DbQuery.GetHashCode();

    public DbQueryProxy<TResult> Include(string path) => _DbQuery.Include(path);

    public override string ToString() => _DbQuery.ToString();

    #endregion DbQuery<TResult>
}
```